# Google street Maps Crash with some error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

i download  Google Maps SDK for iOS along with api key

i import all frameworks along with GoogleMaps.framework and GoogleMaps.bundle.
 in my view controller i write.

```
static CLLocationCoordinate2D kPanoramaNear = {-33.874437, 151.207459};
- (void)loadView
 {

     CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
     panoView_ = [[GMSPanoramaView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     panoView_ = [GMSPanoramaView panoramaWithFrame:applicationFrame    nearCoordinate:kPanoramaNear];
     panoView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
     panoView_.delegate = self;
     panoView_.navigationLinksHidden = YES;
     panoView_.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

     self.view = panoView_;

    [panoView_ moveNearCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.732, 150.312)];
}
```

but my program crashed

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData gtm_dataByInflatingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xe79238'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrecognized selector crashes with the maps SDK are usually caused by missing the `-ObjC` linker flag:

- [error unrecognized selector sent to class while adding Google Map SDK to iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748986/error-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-class-while-adding-google-map-sdk-to-ios6)
- [iOS GoogleMaps SDK error: "Unrecognized selector sent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108418/ios-googlemaps-sdk-error-unrecognized-selector-sent)
- [unrecognized selector sent to class error:google maps sdk code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688050/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-class-errorgoogle-maps-sdk-code)

Comment: i did a small mistake that instead of -ObjC i write -Objc thanks